# Calculations using totals in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi

I have two columns of data, QuestionsAskedDaily and QuestionsAnsweredDaily.

I want to calculate the total percentage of questions which were answered (by dividing the sum of the QuestionsAnsweredDaily column by the QuestionsAskedDaily column).

I know that PowerBI will calculate the sum of each column, but how do I perform a calculation using those sums?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create two measures, one for QuestionsAskedDaily and one for QuestionsAnsweredDaily that look like this:

```
QuestionsAskedDaily = COUNT(<key column from questions table>)
QuestionsAnsweredDaily = COUNT(key column from answers table>)
```

With those two measures in place, you can create a third measure that looks like:

```
AnsweredQuestionsPercent = DIVIDE(QuestionsAskedDaily, QuestionsAnsweredDaily, 0)
```